# Autocrop greyscale image after scanned in browser

Tags: crop, grayscale, image-scanner, dynamic-web-twain, dynamsoft

I am doing scanning using twain driver and using Dynamsoft product for device connection.

Scanner produce greyscale images with huge black border.  How I can do a autocrop and display prefect image to user on the browser.

Comment: Can you share your code and image?

Comment: I am using dynamsoft web twain . https://demo.dynamsoft.com/dwt/online_demo_scan.aspx

Comment: A related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714736/auto-crop-after-scanning-an-image/18758661#18758661

Comment: is the page size set properly? if the page size is set at a larger value than the actual paper, you may see a huge black border

Comment: Now its resolved, installed scanner driver again :)